# Why does ice reduce swelling?

Tags: medicinal-chemistry, injury

It is common practice to use ice packs on injuries that cause bruising and swelling. It seems to be  an effective method to assist in reducing swelling.

Why does ice reduce welling?

Comment: related http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7816/does-putting-an-ice-pack-on-an-injury-reduce-swelling

Comment: It may be due to vasocostrictory effect of cooling. As vessels would constrict less fluid would be lost from the blood.

Comment: @biogirl are you referring to the cells that enter the tissue during inflammation?

Comment: I am referring to narrowing of blood vessels which would reduce both loss of fluid from the blood and the entry of WBCs in the area.

Comment: there are also associated cells that bring fluid to the tissue when damaged

Comment: I don't know whether there are such cells that actually "bring" fluid to the tissues. I just know that histamine released by mast cells cause dilatation of capillaries which would cause fluid from blood to leak out. Are you talking about mast cells?

Comment: I'm too tired at the mo. it's 2.43am to have a discussion about the histology of inflammation.. I find it very interesting.. Please feel free to write an answer.. and I'm sure we'll catch up another day :)

Comment: Alright. Immunity is damn interesting :p

Comment: @biogirl yes it is, I have a horrendous autoimmune disease :/ this has caused me to read many journals.. :/ and much unhappiness.. in my case my body lays down collagen, to plug up the dmamage of destroyed cells, (my cells I have an immunity against).. Anyway.. this is WHY I didn't want to get started! LOL It's a better topic for chat (not the Q) inflammation.. the curse of my life :) Nice to meet you! I am usually on [pets.se] and [cogsci.se]

Comment: @biogirl ah and you're a fellow Aussie! :) I wish my kids were as interested in all this as you are! cheers

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11361/discussion-between-biogirl-and-skippy-ps-im-a-woman)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Swelling is one of the signs of inflammation. Inflammation involves release of histamine by mast cells present in the tissues. Histamine causes vasodilation and leads to leakage of fluid from the blood, along with which neutrophils and other WBCs also enter the area. They phagocytose microbes that might have entered with the injury.

Applying ice would cause vasoconstriction* (i.e. narrowing of blood vessels.) which would reduce the leakage of tissue fluid and hence swelling.

*If you wonder why ice(or any cool thing) causes vasoconstriction think why you turn pale in winter ? Vasoconstriction reduces blood flow to the particular area and hence the exchange of heat is reduced which conserves body heat in cold environments.

Comment: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/11325/what-happens-during-a-raynauds-episode

Comment: Just to add to this- the recommendation for healing using ice is to alternate ice and warm packs so that the fluid exchanges, swelling and then constricting to aid healing - that's where a lot of the relief comes from.